# Whats the best way to wrap a c# class for use by powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an engine that executes powershell scripts, and when they execute, need
to feed back in some xml to the caller. The engine only takes i/o as an idmef xml message. So the script needs to return a similarly formatted xml message. I have a class which does my formatting for me and it would like the script writers to use it.

So question is I want to wrap a c# class to enable it to be used by powershell.

I saw something some where you can refer to c# class using the square bracket mob, eg.

How to you make the c# available to be used like this. I reckon it needs to be made into class lib and somehow loaded into the powershell runtime but how. Also as I'm running the powershell from c#, how do I add it into the environment at that point.

Any help would be appreciated.
Bob.

Comment: Thanks Guys,
I was planning to make it into a cmdlet, but I was sure their was a way to do it via the framework classes without using powershell specifics. 

This will move the wee engine 1 step forward, and 1 big requirement almost completed. Thanks.
Bob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If have an assembly (exe or dll) with the class in it, PowerShell can load it via `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("PathToYourAssembly")`
or in V2

```
Add-Type -Path "PathToYourAsembly"
```

If you are creating a runspace in your application and would like to make an assembly available, you can do that with a [RunspaceConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspaceconfiguration(VS.85).aspx).

```
RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
AssemblyConfigurationEntry myAssembly = new AssemblyConfigurationEntry("strong name for my assembly", "optional path to my assembly");
rsConfig.Assemblies.Append(myAssembly);
Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
myRunSpace.Open();
```

Comment: This example is using it from powershell. Is their anyway to enable the use of the assembly for all scripts, from c# when creating runspace, pipeline etc.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to add an assembly to the runspace configuration.

Comment: Thanks Steven,
Thats is pretty much what I was looking for. 
regards
Bob.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anything is necessary. You can access pretty much the entire .NET Framework from PowerShell. I'm sure they didn't create any wrappers to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with interfaces in PowerShell is very difficult if not impossible at least in V1, so avoid these in your class. In PowerShell a simple [reflection.assembly]::Load or LoadFile is all it takes.

Comment: This example is using it from powershell. Is their anyway to enable the use of the assembly for all scripts, from c# when creating runspace, pipeline etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a Cmdlet in C# that takes a bunch of parameters and spits out the XML that you want. Then you can use that Cmdlet from Powershell by piping things into it.
I hope this helps!